# Django invalid tag error is showing up everytime

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Hi I am writing a Django template and using some nested loops and conditions in it.
Here the main snippet of the template:

```
{% for product in products %}
                {% if product.isVariation == "yes" %}
                    {% for var in product.variations %}

                        <tr>
                          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                            {for image in product.images %}
                                <td><img src="{{image}}" style="height:250px; width:200px;"></td>
                            {% endfor %}
                          <td>{{var.sku}} Condition: {{var.condition}}</td>
                          <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                          <td>{{product.CreatedDateTime}}</td>
                          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Amount" value={{var.units}}></td>
                          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="PKR" value={{var.price}}></td>
                          <td>
                            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
                            <button style="width: 100px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-dark text-white bg-gradient"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
                              </svg> Edit</button>
                            <button style="width: 100px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-dark text-white bg-gradient"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-down" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 10a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h2A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14 9.5v-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 12.5 0h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2 1.5v8A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3.5 11h2a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-2z"/>
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.646 15.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 14.293V5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v8.793l-2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708l3 3z"/>
                              </svg>Save</button>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if product.isVariation == "no" %}
                         <tr>
                          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                            {for image in product.images %}
                                <td><img src="{{image}}" style="height:250px; width:200px;"></td>
                            {% endfor %}
                          <td>{{product.sku}} Condition: {{product.condition}}</td>
                          <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                          <td>{{product.CreatedDateTime}}</td>
                          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Amount" value={{product.units}}></td>
                          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="PKR" value={{product.price}}></td>
                          <td>
                            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
                            <button style="width: 100px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-dark text-white bg-gradient"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
                              </svg> Edit</button>
                            <button style="width: 100px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-dark text-white bg-gradient"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-down" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 10a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h2A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14 9.5v-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 12.5 0h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2 1.5v8A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3.5 11h2a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-2z"/>
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.646 15.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 14.293V5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v8.793l-2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708l3 3z"/>
                              </svg>Save</button>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
```

But it is Throwing this templatesytaxerror:

> Invalid block tag on line 94: 'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

I tried to look some indentation errors or some blocktag that is not correct but found nothing.
Is there any mistake I made that I overlooked or anything? Any response is appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a percent sign from a couple of your tags - `{for image in product.images %}` should be `{% for image in product.images %}`

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem how did I overlooked that